# Why does passing a std::string to CString.Format() only crash sometimes?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-strings, stdstring

Using `CString.Format()`, I'm passing it a `std::map` that returns a `std::string` when given an `int`.

So:

```
CString cStr;
cStr.Format("%s", IntToStdStringMap[1]);
```

where `IntToStdStringMap[1]` returns some string, we'll say "Hello, World!". The issue is that this doesn't seem to crash every time. Eventually, I'll receive an access violation.

Why might this be?

Keep in mind, that changing the code to the following:

```
CString cStr;
cStr.Format("%s", IntToStdStringMap[1].c_str());
```

alleviates the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Small string optimisation, probably. But it's still undefined behaviour, so not really worth reasoning about.

Comment: The docs for CString::Format even talk about not passing objects for the format parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @MillieSmith I agree. The chance of the std::string being passed to CString::Format was an accident showing the undefined behavior. I was just interested in learning more about why this didn't error at compile time. I believe Neil is on to something.

Comment: @NeilButterworth that was my thought as well. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You should not pass object to C ellipsis `...` .

Comment: "*I was just interested in learning more about why this didn't error at compile time*" - because `Format()` is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), its only concrete parameter at compile-time is the `lpszFormat` parameter, the rest of the parameters are caller-defined and evaluated at runtime based on the content of `lpszFormat`.  Many compilers do not (some do) validate the data types passed to variadic parameters at compile-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a `std::string` to `CString::Format` is not right. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327(v=vs.60).aspx:

> The format has the same form and function as the format argument for the printf function.

That means, when the format specifier is `%s`, the expected argument type is `char const*`, not `std::string`.

Hence, use of

```
cStr.Format("%s", IntToStdStringMap[1]);
```

is cause for undefined behavior while the behavior of

```
cStr.Format("%s", IntToStdStringMap[1].c_str());
```

is well defined.

Comment: Correct. I agree with that their may have been some small string optimization happening that didn't cause an issue at compile time. Either way, I'm satisfied with labeling it as undefined behavior and moving on. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @FrankPalmasani, some compilers are able to detect that the argument type does not match the format specifier when the function is `printf`. I am not sure whether they are able to detect the problem at compiler time when the function is `CString::Format`. Who knows what code was generated by the compiler. We can't try to make sense of undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: Some compilers do support compile-time validation of printf-style parameters, but they are usually either 1) hard-coded just to `printf` and its related functions, or 2) expose a special compiler directive that must be applied manually to mark printf-like functions. For example, [Visual Studio 2015 is hard-coded](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/22/format-specifiers-checking/), whereas [GCC has a `format` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).